# Unable to install canvas on MacOS M2

Tags: node.js, npm, canvas, node-gyp

I can't seem to install canvas.

I have tried the steps outlined in the answer here: [node-gyp error when running npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45943701/node-gyp-error-when-running-npm-install)

```
sudo npm uninstall -g node-gyp
sudo npm install -g node-gyp
brew install pkg-config cairo libpng jpeg giflib
npm i canvas
```

But get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/j/Documents/GitHub.nosync/bucket/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --update-binary
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=/Users/j/Documents/GitHub.nosync/bucket/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/j/Documents/GitHub.nosync/bucket/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.10
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.18.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.0/canvas-v2.11.0-node-v93-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.0/canvas-v2.11.0-node-v93-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.11.0 and node@16.18.0 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.0/canvas-v2.11.0-node-v93-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.18.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.18.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.8 found at "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/j/Documents/GitHub.nosync/bucket/node_modules/canvas/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/j/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.18.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/j/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.18.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/j/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.18.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/j/Documents/GitHub.nosync/bucket/node_modules/canvas',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! Package pixman-1 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
npm ERR! Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pixman-1.pc'
npm ERR! to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
npm ERR! No package 'pixman-1' found
npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pixman-1 --libs' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:284:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:293:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 22.3.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary" "--module=/Users/j/Documents/GitHub.nosync/bucket/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/Users/j/Documents/GitHub.nosync/bucket/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v93"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/j/Documents/GitHub.nosync/bucket/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.18.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=/Users/j/Documents/GitHub.nosync/bucket/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/j/Documents/GitHub.nosync/bucket/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/j/Documents/GitHub.nosync/bucket/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1100:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 22.3.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/j/Documents/GitHub.nosync/bucket/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/j/Documents/GitHub.nosync/bucket/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.18.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.10
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

I have also tried installing canvas using `yarn add canvas`, but it appears to give the same error.

Restarting my computer doesn't appear to have any effect either.

I am using a Mac M2 running Ventura 13.2.1, with node version v16.18.0 and npm version 8.19.2

Answer (score 2):

This work form me

```
arch -arm64 brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg
```

And after that try to install canvas

Based on this link:

Comment: I appear to be getting the same error as before unfortunately. Should I try uninstalling or removing anything first before running what you've suggested?

Answer (score 1):

Use Brew to install the necessary dependencies:
`brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg pixman`

Ensure you have `setuptools` installed for Python. Check using:
`pip3 show setuptools`

---

If not, use Brew to install that as well:
`brew install python-setuptools`

If Brew does not manage your Python versions, you can use `pip3` to install `setuptools` instead:
`pip3 install setuptools`

---

After this, `npm install canvas` should work.

**Versions:**

- **Node:** 20.11.1
- **NPM:** 10.2.0
- **Python:** 3.12.2
- **MacOS:** Sonoma 14.3.1
- **Homebrew:** 4.2.14